# Error on deployment Qlib-Server using docker-compose

Tags: python-3.x, docker-compose

Hi I've tried to use qlib-server using [qlib-server one-click-deployment](https://qlib-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#one-click-deployment-with-docker-compose) when the docker up in the detail show the following errors:

```
[1:MainThread](2023-06-10 19:01:55,791) INFO - qlib.Initialization - [config.py:417] - default_conf: server.
[1:MainThread](2023-06-10 19:01:56,212) INFO - qlib.Initialization - [__init__.py:74] - qlib successfully initialized based on server settings.
[1:MainThread](2023-06-10 19:01:56,213) INFO - qlib.Initialization - [__init__.py:76] - data_path={'__DEFAULT_FREQ': PosixPath('/data/stock_data/qlib_data')}
[1:MainThread](2023-06-10 19:01:56,403) ERROR - qlib.workflow - [utils.py:41] - An exception has been raised[ImportError: cannot import name 'run_with_reloader' from 'werkzeug.serving' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py)].
[1:MainThread](2023-06-10 19:01:56,403) ERROR - qlib.workflow - [utils.py:41] - An exception has been raised[ImportError: cannot import name 'run_with_reloader' from 'werkzeug.serving' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py)].
```

How can i solve this problem?

I hope to use qlib in online mode. However, following the steps in the documentation, I was unable to run qlib-server correctly.